# Artifactory: using NetScaler as a reverse proxy for Docker

Tags: docker, artifactory, netscaler

I have to set Artifactory up to work with Docker registries and I am afraid I need some help.

I understand that Docker repositories need a reverse proxy to get an individual address for each repository so the client is happy basically. The question is how to do that.
To be honest I don't know much about Docker and I don't have access to our NetScaler which is our reverse proxy. Our external partner unfortunately isn't exactly helpful either. Plus I'm completely new to Artifactory - perfect prerequisites really .... ;)

I have a redirect from a unique address https://docker1-artifactory.xyz.com to http://artifactory.xyz.com/artifactory/api/docker/docker1 but somehow this doesn't work.
My docker colleague is telling me the redirect has to be transparent, the NetScaler guy tells me that doesn't work.

So do I really need to scrap the whole NetScaler thing and set up my own Apache on my Artifactory server or is there a way to get this working?

EDIT:
I found out that there are some reverse proxy settings in Artifactory that you can configure: the reverse proxy settings from the admin-menu and then there is a field in the advanced configurations tab of the docker repository itself that you can set.
But there is always some information about copying the configuration - do the settings that I insert there have any meaning within Artifactory or is it just for copying?

I'm having a few problems with that configuration since our server can be reached via https://artifactory.xyz.com but the docker repositories cannot be used via subdomains because the certificate only works for the first level, not for sub-subdomains, so I can't use https://docker.artifactory.xyz.com.
Therefore we thought we'd use https://docker-artifactory.xyz.com and redirect that to the correct path - but that obviously doesn't go together with the configuration in the reverse proxy settings because the server url that is set there doesn't fit..
Documentation isn't the greatest either in this case I'm afraid, I can't find any information about that on the Artifactory site

Answer (score 0):

For the record in case someone else struggles with this in the future

1. You just need to do the correct URL rewrites on Netscaler. I dont see how this cannot be solved with a traditional Netscaler
2. Go Netscaler CPX if you need a micro-loadbalancer to do L7 load balance or load balance in general. you can fetch Netscaler CPX from store.docker.com

Comment: Well, that's exactly the question: what are the "correct" URL rewrites? "Correct" as in correct targets and checking typos etc. - we did that. So that's not really it.
What we are trying to do now is to try again with the new Artifactory version but we haven't gotten around to trying that, so we still need to try that

Comment: Its just http. Modify the host header on request and response side. If you need to modify the url modify the url on request and response side aswell. Use fiddler / browser developer tools and look your http payload.